# Thread problem in android?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Consider i have one thread as a separate class , for example SimpleThread.java,

```
class SimpleThread extends Thread {

  public SimpleThread(String str) {
    super(str);
    }
    public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + getName());
            try {
        sleep((int)(Math.random() * 1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("DONE! " + getName());
    }
}
```

from my android home.java i need to start the thread,

```
new SimpleThread("Jamaica").start();
```

once the loop end i need to shoe the alert,but when i use

```
 authalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

it shows null pointer execption, i need a context over here in thread class , is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey you should use Handler for this
 here is the code ...

```
ProgressDialog _progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Saving Data","Please wait......");
settintAdater();

 private void settingAdater(){

        Thread _thread = new Thread(){

            public void run() {

                Message _msg = new Message();
                _msg.what = 1; 
                 // Do your task where you want to rerieve data to set in adapet
                YourCalss.this._handle.sendMessage(_msg);
            };
        };
        _thread.start();
    }
 Handler _handle = new Handler(){

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            switch(msg.what){

                case 1:
                    _progressDialog.dismiss();
                     listview.setAdapter();
            }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of solving your problem is using Handlers, as Sujit suggested. Other way is using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Read [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is : when you launch the thread, the Compiler will not wait until the thread finish his treatement , he will execute the next instruction (  **authalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);** )

so there are two or three ways to do this :

1) , use handler

2) define your own listener for your thread in order to listen until he finished his treatement ,

3) you can pass the Context of your activity , and at the last line of your run method , display the AlertDialog ( with `Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable);` )

Comment: You do realize that Compiler has nothing to do with runtime and waiting specifically?

Comment: Sorry for my english , i'm not so good , and i dont know how to explain it , 
i want to say that , at the moment of the execution of ( Thread.start() ; ) , the program will execute the next instruction , and he will not wait for the thread until he finished his treatement , so i suggest to define a listener on your thread , which wil listen the end of the thread, and then he can display the AlertDialog :) , you understand me ?

Answer (score 0):

You should read http://www.aviyehuda.com/2010/12/android-multithreading-in-a-ui-environment/   and http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

one way would be put a handler in your calling activity:

```
final mContext=this;
final Handler mHandler=new Handler(){

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    int yourIntReturnValue=msg.what;
    //cast your object back to whatever it was lets say it was a string:
    // String yourString=(String) msg.obj;
    //do something like authalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);


}
};
```

then

```
class SimpleThread extends Thread {
   Handler mHandler;

public SimpleThread(String str, Handler h) { 

super(str);
mHandler=h;
 } 
public void run() { 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
System.out.println(i + " " + getName()); 
try { 
sleep((int)(Math.random() * 1000)); 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
} 
System.out.println("DONE! " + getName()); 
 Message.obtain(mHandler, someIntRetValue,
                "DONE"  ).sendToTarget();


}
 }
```